# Why can't a finitely generated module over a PID be generated by fewer elements than the number of invariant factors?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

Suppose $V$ is a finitely generated module over the a PID with $n$ invariant factors. Why can't $V$ be generated by fewer than $n$ elements?

Is there a quick linear algebra reason?

Comment: Over $\Bbb{Z}$ I would use a counting argument: the number of torsion elements (of order that is a common prime divisor of those invariant factors) is determined by the number of invariant factors. Over a more general PID a modification is needed... such as picking a maximal ideal containing the common factor of those invariant factors. Going to a suitable quotient will then reduce this to a case of a vector space!